# How to deal with user using txt spk

Tags: discussion, languages, posts

Recently, in one of the more niche tags I follow, a new user has cropped up and started answering questions - very well to his credit - but one thing that stands out is his use of shortened "text speak" language. I'm no dinosaur by any means, but I'm not sure that using that sort informal language like that fits Stack Overflow.

Words like "ur" and "plz" crop up a lot, but they are getting upvotes because often the code is correct. Should I correct the language used to the Queen's English or just get over it?

Comment: *Soooo* tempted to re-title `How 2 deal with user....`

Comment: @Pekka: u mean usr

Comment: @Matt sry d00d thx

Comment: Vote to close as Not Constructive is another attractive option.

Comment: @six: for answers?

Comment: @Joachim: vote to close my comment as a failure to read non-textspeak English.

Comment: @Pekka: omg u r bak!

Comment: @Strait yeah! Decided 2 us my rl name 4 a chng

Comment: dude, y u pst dis dup? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60597/should-i-clean-up-txt-msg-speak-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: Since you used the phrase "the Queen's English," see also [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us) and [What's the deal with retagging from UK English to US English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/whats-the-deal-with-retagging-from-uk-english-to-us-english).

Comment: @Popular i dint no, hard 2 srch 4 shrt wordz

Comment: @Pekka: Didn't you ask us to drink more rice milk yesterday - seriously?

Comment: @Hendrik I did, but didn't have the time and *Muße* to write a good text, so I rolled back.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Should I correct the language used to the queens english or just get
>   over it?

You should correct it. Not only is text speak infuriating, it must be completely impenetrable to those users for whom English is not their primary language. The programming issues we're tackling here are complex enough without having to work to decipher the language used to explain them.

In my humble opinion it'd also be worth dropping the user a comment to ask him/her to use full English, and even to flag to a moderator any repeat offenders who simply refuse to mend their ways.

Comment: "Not only is text speak infuriating [...] IMHO"? lol...

Comment: @H.B. `IMHO` iz not part of the txt spk that we all h8.

Comment: Thts db8abl tbh

Comment: I fxd it nw. l8rs.

Comment: I ♥ `ygm` -----

Comment: If this wasn't on Meta, I *would* flag those comments. Because it offends my mind and soul.

Comment: Posted against any other answer, I would too.

Answer (score 16):

Flag him for moderator attention.  We'll drop him a little love note and ask him kindly to stop.

Or, you can just leave him a comment pointing him to this question.  That may work just as well.